# ¿ como puedo solucionar este error de la imagen?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, vscode, npm

[image: al momento de ejecutar node index.js me da este error]

hola amigos tengo rato tratando de solucionar este error para un proyecto que estoy realizando, pero no lo he logrado

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: ¿Qué es "este error en la imagen"? [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Pulsa en [edit] para mostrar el error _como texto, con formato_, y describe también en el título el problema en cuestión.